# Install gradle 3.0 on mac with homebrew

Tags: macos, gradle, homebrew

I just recently switched to mac. For some reasons, I need to install gradle with version 3.0 (exactly 3.0). I could install gradle version 2.14 by using `brew install homebrew/versions/gradle214`, but I couldn't do the same with the version 3.0. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can browse the history of a formula on github. This is the former recipe: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/e7ee228c7354e2071ec8a23ec7fe788d82d9a5be/Formula/gradle.rb. Try to download it and see if you can install the formula from the file.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/), it has all gradle versions:

```
sdk install gradle 3.0
```